# Facing the error during headless run in Jenkins: "WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT "

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, webdriver, robotframework

The error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

appears only during the automation run via Jenkins.

I am trying to run robot framework scripts using **Jenkins in an Ubuntu** Machine. The logs generated as a result of the test run possess blank white screens. [Example of the blank screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqoqF.png)

The same automation **run from the terminal** opens the chrome browser and executes **successfully**.

I have corrected the chrome driver version which was mismatching, removed the proxy settings in Jenkins *(via Manage_Plugins->Advanced->Proxy)*. The browser settings used in test run are as follows:

```
echo "  BROWSER_ARGUMENTS:"
echo "   --no-sandbox"
echo "   --ignore-ssl-errors=yes"
echo "   --ignore-certificate-errors"
echo "   --disable-dev-shm-usage"
echo "   --disable-infobars"
echo "   --disable-dev-shm-usage"
echo "   --disable-browser-side-navigation"
echo "   --disable-gpu"
```

Is there any other configurations that could help resolving the issue?